# Setting up leiningen profiles to multiplex between environments AND multiple mains

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I currently have a setup for my Clojure project which allows me to toggle configuration from `dev` to `test` or `prod` by configuring profiles in Leiningen's project map. The section related to the profiles looks like this:

```
  :main ^:skip-aot myproject.core
  :target-path "target/%s"

  :profiles {:uberjar    {:aot :all}
             :dev        {:env {:clj-env :development
                                :database-uri "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_dev"}}
             :test       {:env {:clj-env :test
                                :database-uri "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_test"}}
             :production {:env {:clj-env :production
                                :database-uri "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"}}})
```

The issue is I would further like to enhance this and be able to toggle between multiple mains. I have seen in other posts that people usually achieve this by configuring the profiles like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023762/leiningen-with-multiple-main-classes).

What I don't know how to do is how to preserve the configuration I have so that profiles correspond to environments but also further configure it in order to be able to choose the main class by simply adding a parameter to `lein run`.

I have figured out that one way is obviously to keep having just one main class and add that multiplexing with actual Clojure code, but I was hoping to be able to do it via lein configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple options, the only way I have found to do this is via `aliases`.

First setting the `:main` option to nil, so the MANIFEST.MF doesn't have any `Main.class` set, and then simply adding a couple of aliases specifying which main class to run.

```
:main nil
:target-path "target/%s"
:aliases {"main1" ["run" "-m" "project.main1.core"]
          "main2" ["run" "-m" "project.main2.core"]}
```

Comment: You can do this from the command line, too:  `lein run -m project.main1.core` etc. Have you considered this?

Comment: @AlanThompson yeah; I am aware that the alias is nothing but the command aliased. It's pretty much the way to do it, right?

Comment: I would tend to just type it on the command line.  An alias is more valuable if you need to pass in a bunch of command-line params.